# Cyrillic in HelpProvider

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, cyrillic

How can I use Cyrillic strings in Win Form HelpProvider class?

That's what I got now:

```
  this.helpProvider.SetShowHelp(this.gaParametersText, true);
  this.helpProvider.SetHelpString(this.gaParametersText, "Введите переменные в виде границ поиска, например [0;1][0.7;1.9]");
```

It works fine, but there is an encryption problem.

[image]

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HelpProvider is quite outdated. Have  you considered using ToolTip instead?

```
ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
toolTip1.Show("Русский текст", this.gaParametersText)
```

If it's really necessary, I would suggest digging into pInvoking hhctrl.ocx
for example, http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/hhctrl.htmlhelp

Answer (score 1):

It looks likes `HelpProvider` is poorly implemented.  See this comment on [HelpProvider and Unicode](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/windows/en-us/5e057bf4-c1d2-4099-80e4-8c72ab4cfc35/helpprovider-and-unicode).